# Error after tuleap full installation and setup

Tags: linux, tuleap

I've installed tuleap and run the setup.sh successfully, but the problem is, when I typed, eg: http://mytuleap.domain.com/ web browser is blank, and when I typed 127.0.0.1 also blank.  And when I tried to customize /etc/tuleap/conf/local.inc and /etc/tuleap/conf/database.inc, the file not found. I don't know what hapenned, and I need the solution.

FYI: 
I'm running tuleap8.5 devel-i386 on centos6.7i386 in VMWare Workstation on windows7 32 Bit

this is the message after finish running setup.sh on tuleap
Installation completed successfully!
>

> - WHAT TO DO TO FINISH THE TULEAP INSTALLATION (see /root/todo_tuleap.txt)
> - Automatically generated passwords are stored in /root/.tuleap_passwd
> - Customize /etc/tuleap/conf/local.inc and /etc/tuleap/conf/database.inc
> - You may also want to customize /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
> - Customize /etc/tuleap/site-content information for your site.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the installation guide, Tuleap is meant to work on x86_64 (64 bits) centos systems only.

I don't know if it's possible to virtualize x86_64 machines on a window7 32 bits hosts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, but for me-in fact, i'm able to install and setup according to the user guide. I'm using tuleap development source i386 with centos 6.7 virtualized on my windows 7 32 bit.  perhaps there's a little bit chance for me to know why this error happened, or maybe the i386 is obsolete? thanks, and still need the answer. :)

Comment: You *must* have a x86_64 (and *not* a i386) vm to install Tuleap. So your setup will never work